# How to display the Google Custom Search results in an existing div?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

I want to integrate the Google Custom Search Engine in my website. I have two layers:

```
<div id="left-column"></div>
<div id="right-column"></div>
```

I want to place the search box in the `left-column` where all other menu links are also placed, while I want to place the results in the `right-column`. However, In the `right-column`, some other contents materials are displayed when search is not used.

When a search query is input, I want that the results appear in the `right-column`, removing the displayed contents materials.

I tried

```
customSearchControl.draw('right-column', options);
```

when the search box is drawn; but it erased the contents materials.

How may I do what I want?